# Select the suggestion from live search and show in input type tag

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I have successfully created the live search but now i want to select any one suggestion from available suggestion after searching and show it into input type tag of html. I have used jquery combined with codeigniter. so, below is the code of controller, model and view that contains jquery.

**Controller/users.php:**

```
public function live_search()
        {
            $search=  $this->input->post('customer_name');
            $query = $this->User_model->getCustomer($search);
            echo json_encode ($query);
        }
```

**Model/User_model.php:**

```
function getCustomer($search)
        {
            $this->db->select('customer_name');
            $this->db->like('customer_name', $search, 'both');
            $this->db->from('customer_details');
            $query = $this->db->get();
            return $query->result();
        }
```

**View:**

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            $("#customer_name").keyup(function()
            {
                if($("#customer_name").val().length>2)
                {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "post",
                        url: "http://127.0.0.1/atop/live_search",
                        cache: false,    
                        data:'customer_name='+$("#customer_name").val(),
                        success: function(response){
                        $('#finalResult').html("");
                        var obj = JSON.parse(response);
                        if(obj.length>0)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                var items=[];  
                                $.each(obj, function(i,val)
                                {           
                                    items.push($('<ul/>').text(val.customer_name));
                                }); 
                                $('#finalResult').append.apply($('#finalResult'), items);
                            }
                            catch(e) 
                            {  
                                alert('Exception while request..');
                            }  
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $('#finalResult').html($('<ul/>').text("No Data Found"));  
                        }},
                        error: function()
                        {     
                            alert('Error while request..');
                        }
                });
            }
            return false;
            });
            });
    </script>
<div class="col-md-12">
                        <label>Customer Name:</label><br>
                        <input type="text" name="customer_name"               id="customer_name">
                        <ul id="finalResult"></ul>
                    </div>
```

so, how can i get that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find your way from [this](http://www.dynamicajax.com/fr/AJAX_Suggest_Tutorial-271_290_312.html) link using ajax.